# Random SQLiteDatabaseLockedException

Tags: android-room, android-threading

I am receiving this crash in firebase:

> Fatal Exception:
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is
> locked (Sqlite code 5), (OS error - 11:Try again)        at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:591)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:332)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:311)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:532)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(SQLiteDatabase.java:467)
> at
> androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:78)
> at
> androidx.room.RoomDatabase.internalBeginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:570)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:555)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.StopWorkRunnable.run(StopWorkRunnable.java:56)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)

I am never catch it during the development process, but I am receiving it from Firebase Crashlytics, looks like it kind of random. For database I am using room. Is there any chance that I can fix it by myself?

Seems like the only thing that I am able to do - to update room version, but it does not help. Maybe I need to add some flag to the database.